# Find $\textbf{x}$ such that $\left|\textbf{x}-\textbf{a}\right|=\left|\textbf{x}-\textbf{b}\right|$, for $\textbf{a},\textbf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Using the properties of inner product, it's easy to show that one solution is the midpoint, $\textbf{x}=\frac{1}{2}(\textbf{a}+\textbf{b})$. How do I show that there are other solutions, i.e., all points equidistant from $\textbf{a}$ and $\textbf{b}$?

Comment: Think about the case for k=2...how would you describe the line of points equidistant to a and b given one point on it? (Obviously we can assume a and b are not equal)

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically, the solution set is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment between $a$ and $b$.

In $\mathbb{R}^k$, this is a $k-1$ dimensional hyper-plane. If $k \ge 2$, you have infinitely many solutions.

We can find the hyperplane algebraically as follows:

$\|x-a\| = \|x-b\|$

$\|x-a\|^2 = \|x-b\|^2$

$(x-a)^T(x-a) = (x-b)^T(x-b)$

$x^Tx - x^Ta - a^Tx + a^Ta = x^Tx - x^Tb - b^Tx + b^Tb$

$x^T(b-a) + (b-a)^Tx = b^Tb - a^Ta$

$2(b-a)^Tx = (b^Tb-a^Ta)$

The solution set is $x = \frac{1}{2}(a+b) + v$, where $v$ is any vector orthogonal  to $b-a$.